# How to pass javascript array to php laravel4

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to manage users in laravel4. I have table with users and checkboxes. I want to delete checked users. I select users to delete in this way:

```
var users = new Array();
$("input[type='checkbox']").live("click", function(){
    var id = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);        
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        users.push(id);
        alert(users);
    } else {            
        var index = users.indexOf(id);
        users.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

and then I want to delete this users in my controller deleteUsers. How can I do it?

In route I have this

```
Route::get('/worker/delete', 'UsersController@deleteworker');
```

in action I have

```
$userIds = Input::get('checkbox');
        foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
            $user = DB::table('workers')->find((int) $userId);
            if (!empty($user)) {
                $user->delete();
            }
        }
```

My ajax call looks like:

```
$('#delete').click(function(e){

          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "worker/delete",
            data: { userIds: users } // users - it you array of user ids
          })
          .done(function() {
            alert("Users deleted");
          });
        });
```

and it doesnt works

Comment: Check your controller; $userIds = Input::get('checkbox'); , use : $userIds = Input::get('userIds');

Comment: But my checkbox has name checkbox doest it matter?

Comment: You are sending data in variable userIds 
>data: { userIds: users }

Comment: I changed $userIds but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

first send an ajax request, like this:

```
$('.btn-selector').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropogate();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/worker/destroyByIds",
    data: { userIds: users } // users - it you array of user ids
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert("Users deleted");
  });
});
```

Create a specific route in `routes.php`. In specified action do this.

```
$userIds = Input::get('userIds');
foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
    $user = User::find((int) $userId);
    if (!empty($user)) {
        $user->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to first check checkboxes then click on button and after this I want to delete checked users from table workers. It should be dynamically.

Comment: @user3669253 You want to delete via ajax? By the way, there is no matter how you want to delete them, you just need to get userIds array from the form, and foreach user id delete it.

Comment: Yes I want to delete them via ajax.

Comment: @user3669253 i've modified my answer